How to Deploy S3 Static Websites to Multiple Stages Using CDK Pipeline Without Redundant Builds?
I'm currently working on deploying a static website hosted on S3 to multiple environments (e.g., test, stage, production) using AWS CDK pipelines. I need to  uses the correct backend API URLs and other environment-specific settings for each build.
Current Approach:
1. Building the Web App for Each Stage Separately:
In the Synth step of my pipeline, I’m building the web application separately for each environment by setting environment variables like REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL:
from aws_cdk.pipelines import ShellStep

pipeline = CodePipeline(self, "Pipeline",
    synth=ShellStep("Synth",
        input=cdk_source,
        commands=[
            # Set environment variables and build the app for the 'test' environment
            "export REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=https://api.test.example.com",
            "npm install",
            "npm run build",
            # Store the build artifacts
            "cp -r build ../test-build",

            # Repeat for 'stage'
            "export REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=https://api.stage.example.com",
            "npm run build",
            "cp -r build ../stage-build",

            # Repeat for 'production'
            "export REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=https://api.prod.example.com",
            "npm run build",
            "cp -r build ../prod-build",
        ]
    )
)

2. Deploying to S3 Buckets in Each Stage:
I deploy the corresponding build from the  stage source using BucketDeployment:
from aws_cdk import aws_s3 as s3, aws_s3_deployment as s3deploy


class MVPPipelineStage(cdk.Stage):
    def __init__(
        self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, stage_name: str, **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        build_path = f"../{stage_name}-build"

        website_bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self, f"WebsiteBucket-{stage_name}", public_read_access=True
        )

        s3deploy.BucketDeployment(
            self,
            f"DeployWebsite-{stage_name}",
            sources=[s3deploy.Source.asset(build_path)],
            destination_bucket=website_bucket,
        )

Problem:
While this approach works, it's not ideal because it requires building the same application multiple times (once for each environment), which leads to redundancy and increased build times.
My Question:
Is there a better way to deploy the static website to different stages without having to redundantly build the same application multiple times? Ideally, I would like to:

Build the application once.
Deploy it to multiple environments (test, stage, prod).
Dynamically configure the environment-specific settings (like backend URLs) at deployment time or runtime.

Any advice or best practices on how to optimise this process using CDK pipelines ?
Thank you

How are those environment-specific settings defined/used? You can use DeployTimeSubstitutedFile if they're in a config file.

Thanks gshpychka.  DeployTimeSubstitutedFile exactly what i was looking for.

First you need to change your build to be unlinked to specific host (for example use window.location.hostname instated of hard coded it).
Then you can publish your website (after building it) as an npm package to some private repo (amazon CodeArtifact for example).
then in each stage you:

install the private package
deploy the website

